# how to save the selected array if checkbox is checked in tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arraylist.count
}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = PopupCellTableViewCell()

    cell  = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "advnccell", for: indexPath) as? PopupCellTableViewCell)!

    cell.bgView = Utilities().viewborder(vw: cell.bgView )

    let dict = arraylist[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

    let cd  = dict.value(forKey: "Code") as? String ?? ""
    let desc  = dict.value(forKey: "Description") as? String ?? ""

    cell.tittleLbl.text = cd + " - " + desc

    if selectedRows.contains(indexPath)
    {
        cell.checkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"check"), for: .normal)
    }
    else
    {
        cell.checkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"uncheck"), for: .normal)
    }
    if (cell.checkBtn.currentImage?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "check")))!
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(cell.tittleLbl.text, forKey: "tittle")

    }

     cell.btnAction.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btnAction.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkBoxSelection(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}



// checkbox selection
@objc func checkBoxSelection(_ sender:UIButton)
{
    let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    if self.selectedRows.contains(selectedIndexPath)
    {
        self.selectedRows.remove(at: self.selectedRows.index(of: selectedIndexPath)!)
    }
    else
    {
        self.selectedRows.append(selectedIndexPath)
    }
    self.tableVw.reloadData()
}
```

At present i am getting only one value, how can i get if i selected multiple check buttons

Comment: Provide code what you had tried far?

Comment: Rather than using an extra `selectedRows` array put the `selected` information into the data model as `Bool` value, this is much more efficient and avoids the ugly  `UIImage` comparison. And – as always – don't use `NSArray / NSDictionary` and `value(forKey` in Swift.

Comment: can u tell me clearly??bcz i am fresher @vadian

Comment: Use a custom struct as data model rather than a dictionary and add a `Bool` property `selected`. Use that to set the appropriate button image.

Answer (score 0):

Fix this portion of your code:

```
if selectedRows.contains(indexPath)
{
    cell.checkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"check"), for: .normal)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(cell.tittleLbl.text, forKey: "tittle")
}
else
{
    cell.checkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"uncheck"), for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working, But i want multiple selected data.now i am getting only one string

Comment: i am getting empty array and i want selected array @Carpsen

Comment: @MeMouli What do you mean by "empty array"? And what type is `arraylist`? Same question for `selectedRows`